# Pdf of log of ratio of uniform random variables

Tags: probability, random-variable, uniform-distribution

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are iid $U(0,1)$. I am trying to find the pdf of $W=log(U/(1-V))$. My approach is to suppose $Z = U$ and find the joint density of $(W,Z)$ and get the marginal of $W$. The pdf of $W$ from my calculation came out to be $\frac{1}{2we^{-w}}$. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Since this question already has an accepted answer: Observe that $1-V$ is still a standard uniform distribution and hence, $W$ has a standard [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Related_distributions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$W$ is in range $(-\infty,\infty)$ and your PDF doesn't integrate to $1$ in this range, or even converge. Note that if $V\sim U(0,1)$, then $1-V\sim U(0,1)$. So, the distribution of $\log(U/(1-V))$ is equal to the distribution of $\log(U/V)$, which is $\log U-\log V$. Taking the logarithm of uniform RV and negating it gives you an exponential, i.e. $-\log V$ is exponential with $\lambda=1$. So, the expression we have is a *difference* of two exponentials: $E_v-E_u$. There is already an answer for it in [math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115022/pdf-of-the-difference-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables).

Comment: @ gunes Thank you very much.

Comment: The pdf of W1=log(U) is simply e^(w1). Am I correct?

Comment: So the pdf of  $W_2=-log(V)$ is also $e^{-w_2}$.

Comment: I misread your comment. You're correct for both of them.

Comment: Okay. Then $w_1 <0$ and $w_2>0$.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: The fact at the end (and indeed probably all the others) is also covered in  answers and comments on CV.